# Mongodb is not updated properly from 4.2 to 4.4

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I was using mongodb 4.2.9 on ubuntu 18.04

I installed it with package manager.
Now I to update it to 4.4 version used package manager following --> https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/  instructions.

Installation was ok but when I write `mongod -version` command it shows - `db version v4.2.9`.
I tried to re-install again it says
`mongodb-org is already the newest version (4.4.1).` but `mongod -version` command it shows - `db version v4.2.9`.
How can I get rid of this problem?

Comment: What do `which mongo`, `which mongod`, `dpkg -l|grep mongo` say?

Comment: `mongodb-org    4.4.1 ` , `mongodb-org-mongos    4.2.9`, `mongodb-org-server 4.2.9 `, `mongodb-org-shell  4.2.9`, `mongodb-org-tools 4.2.9` , `mongodb-server 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu1.1 ` ------  by `dpkg -l|grep mongo command`

Comment: I am not being able to set `db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "4.4" } )`  ,,, ` "errmsg" : "Invalid command argument. Expected '4.2' or '4.0', found 4.4 in: { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: \"4.4\" . . . . . . .`

Comment: `apt-get upgrade` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like `mongodb-org` is the meta-package depending on all other packages, but it doesn't require dependent packages to be the same version as it is itself. This works fine for installation but doesn't update dependent packages if you install `mongodb-org` when you already have older individual packages installed.

To fix:

- Simple solution - `apt-get upgrade`. All of the other MongoDB packages should get updated.
- If that doesn't work, manually install all the other packages again: `apt-get install mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools`.

You also have `mongodb-server` in there, you should remove it if it's installed and if it's not installed you may consider purging it after ensuring you don't need any part of its configuration for your present deployment.