# Unable to install or remove mongodb

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I am trying to install mongodb 4.4 by using (running as root): `apt install -y mongodb-org`

but then I got

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not going to be installed
 mongodb-org-tools : Depends: mongodb-database-tools but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So I use `apt --fix-broken install` and got:

```
(Reading database ... 72856 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-server_4.4.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-server (4.4.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-server_4.4.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongod', which is also in package mongodb-server-core 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu1.1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-mongos_4.4.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-mongos (4.4.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-mongos_4.4.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongos', which is also in package mongodb-server-core 1:3.6.3-0ubuntu1.1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-database-tools_100.2.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-database-tools (100.2.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-database-tools_100.2.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/bsondump', which is also in package mongo-tools 3.6.3-0ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-server_4.4.2_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-mongos_4.4.2_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-database-tools_100.2.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So I try to remove mongodb by using: `apt remove mongodb-org` and got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org-tools : Depends: mongodb-database-tools but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongodb is not updated properly from 4.2 to 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63862784/mongodb-is-not-updated-properly-from-4-2-to-4-4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Mongodb is not updated properly from 4.2 to 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63862784/mongodb-is-not-updated-properly-from-4-2-to-4-4/63863423#63863423).

Remove all installed mongodb packages then install the 4.4 ones.

Use `dpkg -l |grep mongodb` to find which ones you have installed.