# Failed to install mongoDB in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, ubuntu, backend

I tried to install MongoDB on the ubuntu 20.04 and the used command are given below,

> To create a mongodb-org-4.4.list file in the sources.list.d folder

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list
```

> Updated the system,

```
sudo apt-get update
```

> Install the MongoDB on my system,

```
sudo apt install mongodb-org
```

After running the above command I just faced an error and it was not install in ubuntu system and the error is given below, please concern who wanna to help me,

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mongodb-org is already the newest version (4.4.5).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not going to be installed
 mongodb-org-tools : Depends: mongodb-database-tools but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

**Note:** The error are also added in attached file.
[image]

Comment: Please confirm you get installation commands from https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/. The ones in the question slightly different.  Did you try "apt --fix-broken install" as the error message suggests? The error says it's already installed, if nothing helps try to remove it `sudo apt-get --purge remove mongodb-org` and install again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63862784/mongodb-is-not-updated-properly-from-4-2-to-4-4/63863423#63863423

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

Answer (score 0):

@Alex Blex, Please concern here,

```
>echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list

>sudo apt-get update

>sudo apt install mongodb-org
```

After running the above command I also run `apt --fix-broken install` this command and it showed an error that is,

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

Then I created an new director in my laptop as **/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend** But it's not solved.

Even I also run `sudo apt-get --purge remove mongodb-org` this command after your suggest and then run all the command again but it's again showed same problems.

And after running `sudo apt-get --purge remove mongodb-org` this command it showed below feedback, please concern here,

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org-tools : Depends: mongodb-database-tools but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Thanks, Everyone!

Comment: I have same problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this command :

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

I use it to install MongoDB and it's working :

tuto : https://addi-kamal.medium.com/mongodb-iceberg-how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-server-9c5beea2c62