# Issue connecting to mongodb atlas via golang on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-atlas

i have been trying to connect to mongodb atlas but I have been getting the following error.

`auth error: sasl conversation error: unable to authenticate using mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-1": (AtlasError) bad auth : Authentication failed.`

I have also whitelisted my IP on the at mongodb atlas GUI...

THE URI link is for the go application with version 1.0 and later

Following is my code

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
)

const (
    // Name of the database.
    DBName = "Stats"
    // Name of the collections
    notesCollection = "notes"
    URI = "mongodb+srv://<username><password>@inshorts.0wwoh.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
)

type Note struct {
    ID        primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id" json:"id,omitempty"`
    Title     string             `json:"title"`
    Body      string             `json:"body"`
    CreatedAt time.Time          `bson:"created_at" json:"created_at,omitempty"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time          `bson:"updated_at" json:"updated_at,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    // Options to the database.
    clientOpts := options.Client().ApplyURI(URI)
    client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, clientOpts)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    db := client.Database(DBName)
    coll := db.Collection(notesCollection)
    fmt.Println(coll.Name()) // output: notes

    note := Note{}
    // An ID for MongoDB.
    note.ID = primitive.NewObjectID()
    note.Title = "First note"
    note.Body = "Some spam text"
    note.CreatedAt = time.Now()
    note.UpdatedAt = time.Now()
    result, err := coll.InsertOne(ctx, note)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    // ID of the inserted document.
    objectID := result.InsertedID.(primitive.ObjectID)
    fmt.Println(objectID)

}
```

I am using atlas because I am having issues installing MongoDB in my system( i followed this `https://stackoverflow.com/a/67719154/14409588` ), whenever I run `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org` I get the following error

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mongodb-database-tools mongodb-mongosh mongodb-org-database
  mongodb-org-database-tools-extra mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server
  mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed
  mongodb-database-tools mongodb-mongosh mongodb-org mongodb-org-database
  mongodb-org-database-tools-extra mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server
  mongodb-org-shell mongodb-org-tools
0 to upgrade, 9 to newly install, 0 to remove and 25 not to upgrade.
Need to get 0 B/144 MB of archives.
After this operation, 436 MB of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 unknown system user 'mongodb' in statoverride file; the system user got removed
before the override, which is most probably a packaging bug, to recover you
can remove the override manually with dpkg-statoverride
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

so since i cannot install mongo i cannot check through my terminal if the URI is actually working, but i am pretty sure the URI is correct as it has been copied from the atlas gui itself

Comment: Did you replace `<username>:<password>` with your actual username and password in the URI in your actual code?

Comment: Yes, obviously :)
just did not want to put the credentials here

Comment: It's not obvious, especially since the error clearly indicates that your credentials possibly are wrong. Like trying to use the username/password for your atlast account instead of having a database user created, or simply mistyping the username/password are both plausible explanations.

Comment: Alright ... Understood

Comment: To use in your system prefer using Docker .... It is easier and doesn't give you compatibility problem with your system. And keeps you system clean.

Comment: Check for special chars in the username and password.... maybe is conflicting...