# How to fix Install mongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I always get an error code when I install any package. Please help me how to fix it so that I don't have the below situation. I run:
 `sudo apt install mongodb-org`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mongodb-org is already the newest version (4.4.3).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not installable
               Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not installable
 mongodb-org-tools : Depends: mongodb-database-tools but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63862784/mongodb-is-not-updated-properly-from-4-2-to-4-4/63863423#63863423

Comment: It seems that you already have installed the newest version `mongodb-org is already the newest version (4.4.3)`.