# "mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not going to be installed" when installing mongodb in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu

I've committed the error of installing mongodb first by `sudo apt install mongodb`, removing it and then trying to install as the [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) says so for Ubuntu 20.04 (Linux Mint), but now I can't install any other package because it gives me:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not going to be installed
 mongodb-org-tools : Depends: mongodb-database-tools but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Tried `sudo apt reinstall`  `sudo apt --fix-broken install` `sudo apt purge <package_name>` `sudo apt remove <package_name>` `sudo apt-get install -f`

When running `sudo apt install --fix-broken`:

```
sudo apt install --fix-broken            
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mongodb-database-tools mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mongodb-database-tools mongodb-org-mongos mongodb-org-server
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/89,2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 148 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 414079 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-server_4.4.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-server (4.4.6) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-server_4.4.6_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongod', which is also in package mongodb-server-core 1:3.6.9+really3.6.8+90~g8e540c0b6
d-0ubuntu5
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-org-mongos_4.4.6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-org-mongos (4.4.6) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-mongos_4.4.6_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/mongos', which is also in package mongodb-server-core 1:3.6.9+really3.6.8+90~g8e540c0b6
d-0ubuntu5
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../mongodb-database-tools_100.3.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mongodb-database-tools (100.3.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-database-tools_100.3.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/bsondump', which is also in package mongo-tools 3.6.3-0ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-server_4.4.6_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-org-mongos_4.4.6_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-database-tools_100.3.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

If I try to reinstall mongodb following the official doc it gives me again the same error I've mentioned before.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63862784/mongodb-is-not-updated-properly-from-4-2-to-4-4/63863423#63863423

Comment: @D.SM Tried that already, can't install any new packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.
`sudo apt-get clean`

`sudo pkexec synaptic` >> filter by "broken" >> remove completely the package

`sudo apt-get install -f`

Tanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This solved my problem;
`dpkg -l | grep mongo` will show the list of packages, then `dpkg -r <nameofpkg>` could be used for each packages for the output of `dpkg -l | grep mongo`.